# Some keys don't work after clean up of laptop

Tags: laptop, keyboard, motherboard, cleaning

Today I purchased some thermal paste and a can of air to clean my laptop after two years of use. I never had a problem with this computer. Also I never opened a laptop before, so I saw a video of someone disassembling this model (sleekbook 14 HP). The only issue i had was that my laptop had two hidden screws and before I realized that, I forced a little bit the cover (the palm rest), the part that is under the keyboard and over the motherboard.

The only keys not working are: `ENTER, BACKSPACE, SPACE, ARROW UP, ARROW DOWN`. My computer model is **sleekbook 14-f004la**. An external keyboard works fine. I checked with `xev` and there is no event when those keys are pressed.

What should I do? Did I break the keyboard or the motherboard?

Comment: You probably have to open up the laptop to look for any misaligned connection.

Comment: You know, the keyboard connects through a ribbon directly to the motherboard, I double checked it, I think it's hard to get it wrong.